# Partitioning SD card on Android phone

Tags: sd-card, partitions

I have a 32GB SD card which I want to have it partitioned.

I'm having the hardest time finding any apps that work or any tutorials.

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you rooted? There is no way to edit partitioning directly from the device without root, once you have root privileges, there are several apps which allow for the card to partitioned, such as [AParted](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sylkat.AParted) or [Parted4Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.giis.parted4Android&hl=en).

If you have custom recovery, such as TWRP or CWM, some of those builds have SD card partitioning built in.

Remember that Android will only mount one SD card partition by default, with root you can manually mount a second partition.

Answer (score -1):

You can partition through recovery (CWM) when u go  to advanced options in cwm recovery the option is present over there.